# txtProgressBar() not showing with foreach() in R

Tags: r, foreach, progress-bar

I can't visualize the progress-bar when working with foreach in R (I'm working on Windows):

```
library(doParallel)

total <- 200
registerDoParallel(cores=4)
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max =total , style =3)
res <- foreach(i = 1:total ) %dopar% {
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  }
close(pb)
```

An idea? I've seen similar questions but the solutions provided didn't help...

Thanks